# Adding values of 2 arrays in combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, jagged-arrays

I have a combo box in my WFA. I want it to display a item name and the price in the combo box . The item name and price are stored in two different columns of the database table.

```
string qw = "select wine from cms.menulist";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(qw, mycon);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt1);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string wine = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(wine); 
        }
```

i used the above code to retrive the item name in the combobox. so whenever i add items in the database the items of the combobox updates accordingly.

now along with the item name(ie wine in this case) i also want itz price to be displayed next to the item name. the price is stored in the same table but a different column named wine_price.

eg i want the combobox options to be as follows

redwine $20
white wine $40

Comment: Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? An example would be nice.

Comment: This is not a jagged-array. Just Format the values into a single string (if that is all you need)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd take a look at the question i have edited it

Comment: @Brian - it is still not a jagged array.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd could u explain ur answer with an example

Comment: A jagged array is an array of arrays that have different lengths. In this case this is an array of objects and the objects have all the same number of elements (Name and price) See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd i have edited the qustion plz have a look and help with a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a class that represents name and price, you could simple override `ToString` and then add instances of that class:

```
public class NameAndPrice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1:c}", Name, Price);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}

NameAndPrice a = new NameAndPrice() { Name = "Hello", Price = 1.25d };
comboBox1.Items.Add(a);
```

So for each row in the database table, create one instance of `NameAndPrice` and add it to your `ComboBox`.